# Send Email after Account is created - Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, singleemailmessage

Create a trigger to create a task when account is created, associate the created task to the account and send a email to notify the owner that account and task has been created. Below is the code but i am hitting below error

> Apex trigger CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: User:{Email=dg@abc.com, Id=0055g00000Bze7aAAB}: [toAddresses, User:{Email=dg@abc.com, Id=0055g00000Bze7aAAB}]: Trigger.CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount: line 34, column 1

Please forgive my bad coding methods I am trying my best.

```java
Trigger CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount on Account(after Insert){

    List<Task> createtask = new List<Task>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
    for(Account acc: trigger.new){
        //Create task record
        Task t = new Task();
        t.subject = 'Account Created :' + acc.Name;
        t.whatId = acc.Id;
        t.OwnerId = acc.OwnerId;
        t.ActivityDate =  date.today();
        t.Status = 'Not Started';
        createtask.add(t);
    
        //Send Email Notification
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        list<user> sentTo = [Select Email From User where Id =: acc.OwnerId];
        Map<Id,String> userEmail = new Map<Id,String>();
        
        for(User a : sentTo){
            userEmail.put(a.Id, string.valueof(a));
        }
        
        mail.setToAddresses(userEmail.values());
        mail.setSubject('New Account and a Task related to it are created');
        String body = 'A new Account ' + acc.id + '& a new Task has been created';
        mail.setHTMLBody(body);
        mails.add(mail);
        
    }
    
    insert createtask;
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: If your approach continues to simply send the email to one single recipient, whose email is already captured in a contact, lead, or user record, use the solution proposed by @Ankaiah Bandi. In these instances, using `setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)` is the best approach because it is faster, simpler, and requires no additional SOQL queries.

---

To directly answer your question, when you attempt to collect the user emails on these lines:

```
    for(User a : sentTo){
        userEmail.put(a.Id, string.valueof(a));
    }
```

You Should be accessing the email of the user, instead of the User object itself:

```
    for(User a : sentTo){
        userEmail.put(a.Id, String.valueof(a.Email));
    }
```

After taking a few minutes to look through this, there are several issues with your approach, the most severe being that you have a SOQL query in your loop. Here's a partially re-written trigger that fixes both of these issues:

```
trigger CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount on Account(after insert){
    List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    //Container to collect Account Owner IDs, for later bulkified query
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account acc : (List<Account>) Trigger.new){
        //Create task record
        Task t = new Task();
        t.subject = 'Account Created :' + acc.Name;
        t.whatId = acc.Id;
        t.OwnerId = acc.OwnerId;
        t.ActivityDate =  date.today();
        t.Status = 'Not Started';
        tasksToInsert.add(t);
        // collect the account owner IDs.
        ownerIds.add(acc.OwnerId);
    }
    // You don't want to run SOQL queries inside loops. Instead, aggregate values and query in bulk.
    Map<Id, User> accountOwners = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :ownerIds]);
    for(Account acc: (List<Account>)Trigger.new){    
        //Send Email Notification
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        User recipient = accountOwners.get(acc.OwnerId);
        List<String> recipientEmailAddresses = new List<String>{String.valueOf(recipient.Email)};
        mail.setToAddresses(recipientEmailAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('New Account and a Task related to it are created');
        // You may want to put the account name in here instead?
        String body = 'A new Account ' + acc.id + '& a new Task has been created';
        mail.setHTMLBody(body);
        messages.add(mail);
    }
    
    insert tasksToInsert;
    Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer......it solved the issue plus I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `setTargetObjectId` as Account `ownerId` in the `Messaging.singleEmailMessage` object.

you can modify the code as like below.

```
Trigger CreateTaskAssociatedWithAccount on Account(after Insert){

    List<Task> createtask = new List<Task>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
    for(Account acc: trigger.new){
        //Create task record
        Task t = new Task();
        t.subject = 'Account Created :' + acc.Name;
        t.whatId = acc.Id;
        t.OwnerId = acc.OwnerId;
        t.ActivityDate =  date.today();
        t.Status = 'Not Started';
        createtask.add(t);
        //Send Email Notification
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    //Here directly assign the account ownerid to the setTargetObjectId.         
        mail.setTargetObjectId(acc.OwnerId);
        mail.setSubject('New Account and a Task related to it are created');
        String body = 'A new Account ' + acc.id + '& a new Task has been created';
        mail.setHTMLBody(body);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mails.add(mail);
        
    }
    
    insert createtask;
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```